# Listing all user accounts on a workstation

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, usmt

I am working on a script for backing up user profiles from workstations to server with USMT and I am running into a snag finding a way to list profiles on the workstations. All our profiles are domain based and every article I can find only list local profiles, not domain accounts.

I was curious to see if anyone has an easy way to do this or how others are approaching this? I had thought about just listing the folders in C:\Users and then cross referencing AD to grab domain accounts however part of the project is to be able to grab accounts off other domains and join them to another so don't think that would work.

So if anyone can give me some pointers or articles that talk about this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: the following will list out the non-system profiles on a system >>> `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {-not $_.Special}` <<<

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I should be able to parse those results to pull that data I am wanting.

Comment: @Caleb - you are most welcome ... glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like you want a list of account profiles on the local system. the most direct method i know of is to use the `Win32_UserProfile` class.

what the code does ...

- grabs all the account profiles
  you can use the `-Filter` parameter to get only the ones you want, but i don't understand the query language dialect used by CIM/WMI.
- filters out the `.Special` accounts
  things like the `systemprofile` are not likely to be wanted. [*grin*]
- wraps the call in `@()` to force the result to be an array
  the point here is to make SURE that the result is an array - even if there only one item in it. it can be useful to treat the result as an array, so i forced it to be one.
- assigns the result to a $Var
- displays that list

the code ...

```
$UserProfileList = @(
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
        Where-Object {-not $_.Special}
    )

$UserProfileList
```

output for just one profile ...

```
AppDataRoaming                   : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Contacts                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Desktop                          : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Documents                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Downloads                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Favorites                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
HealthStatus                     : 3
LastAttemptedProfileDownloadTime : 
LastAttemptedProfileUploadTime   : 
LastBackgroundRegistryUploadTime : 
LastDownloadTime                 : 
LastUploadTime                   : 
LastUseTime                      : 2021-11-08 12:02:02 PM
Links                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Loaded                           : True
LocalPath                        : C:\Users\[MyUserName]
Music                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Pictures                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
RefCount                         : 
RoamingConfigured                : False
RoamingPath                      : 
RoamingPreference                : 
SavedGames                       : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Searches                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
SID                              : S-1-5-[MySID]
Special                          : False
StartMenu                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Status                           : 0
Videos                           : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
PSComputerName                   :
```

you can cross reference the profile with your accounts by the `.LocalPath` OR get the exact account by using the `SID` to do a lookup.